# Classical Theory of Fields: Energy-momentum tensor, error on page 80?

Tags: special-relativity, terminology, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, textbook-erratum

I'm trying to understand the physical significance/interpretation of the various parts of the [stress-energy-momentum tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor). The book I'm using is *The Classical Theory of Fields*, by Landau and Lifshitz.

On page 80 of my edition (requires login):

https://archive.org/details/classicaltheoryo0000land_k6k2/page/80/mode/2up?view=theater

there seems to be an error in this remark, but I'm not 100% certain:

> Thus we arrive at the important conclusion that the requirements of
> relativistic invariance, as expressed by the tensor character of the
> quantities Tik, automatically lead to a definite connection between
> the energy flux and the **momentum flux**: the energy flux density is
> equal  to the **momentum flux density** multiplied by c^2.

As I read it, both items which I rendered in bold in the above quote should be changed to read **momentum density**. Am I correct, or have I strayed into the wilderness?

Please note that in the text the momentum density is noted on the page previous to the one cited above, page 79:

https://archive.org/details/classicaltheoryo0000land_k6k2/page/78/mode/2up?view=theater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct; looking at the 2000 edition on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0750627689) (page 85 by searching for momentum density in the Look Inside feature) that section has been updated to read momentum density.